# Gmail email expanded content position

Tags: php, html, email, gmail, phpmailer

Gmail has this button which hides *what it **thinks*** is the signature from the body of the email unless the user clicks on it:

[image]

However, it is not being placed at the right position in my HTML emails by default. Is there any way I can designate where this button should be placed so that Gmail doesn't mark half of my email as the signature?

Comment: I face the same problem.  Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Under Settings (the cog icon drop down on the upper right hand side) go to General tab. Scroll down to Signature and try out this setting:
Insert this signature before quoted text in replies and remove the "--" line that precedes it.

it does not work 100% of the time, but works often enough.

Comment: I apologize as I did not explain better. I am sending this as an HTML email through PHP; not Gmail. Gmail simply renders this signature button in awkward places.